# iframes from same domain and cross browser scripting

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser

Say a page served from foo.bar.com/parent.htm contains an iframe that points to bar.com/child.htm.

Can a script located in parent.htm call a function defined in child.htm?

Seems like this should work because parent.htm and child.htm both eminate from the same domain.  I am getting an access denied message, but I would like to know why?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Look at Wikipedia, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

> To illustrate, the following table gives an overview of typical outcomes
> for checks against the URL "http://www.example.com/dir/page.html".
>
> http://v2.www.example.com/dir/other.html - Failure - Different host (exact match required)

Answer (score 1):

They are **not** considered the same domain from the browser's standpoint

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Hosting services that use subdomains for different clients need to isolate them safely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set `document.domain = 'bar.com'` in both pages and you can then access data cross-frame.  This only works on the same domain, e.g. you can't set `document.domain` to "not-the-current-domain.com"

Or what I usually do:

```
document.domain = document.domain.replace(/.*?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$/, '$1');
```

which sets `document.domain` to the current root domain (e.g. strips any sub-domains)